# Emitting from inside of a component to the super component

Tags: angular, plaid, angular-event-emitter

I have this component where I have a @output emitter called plaidLinkSuccess and I am trying to emit it in the onSuccess callback function of the LinkHandler interface as shown below. Now I have debugged it and it does hit the emitter in onSuccess() but the parent of PlaidComponent doesn't pick up anything.

PlaidComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-plaid',
  templateUrl: './plaid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./plaid.component.scss'],
})
export class PlaidComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output()
  static plaidLinkSuccess = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @Input()
  plaidLinkToken: string;
  plaidResponse = false;
  env = 'sandbox'; // todo
  handler: LinkHandler;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.handler = Plaid.create({
      clientName: 'JJInc', // todo
      env: this.env,
      token: this.plaidLinkToken,
      product: ['auth'],

      onLoad() {},
      onSuccess(public_token, metadata) {
        console.log(public_token);
        console.log(metadata);
        PlaidComponent.plaidLinkSuccess.emit({
          publicToken: public_token,
          accountId: metadata.account.id,
        });
      },
      onExit(err, metadata) {
        console.log(err);
        // The user exited the Link flow.
        if (err != null) {
          // bankAccountInfoPlaidComponent.logError(err);
        }
      },
    });
  }

  onPlaidClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.linkHandler();
  }

  linkHandler() {
    this.handler.open();
  }
}
```

PlaidComponents' Parent HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isPlaid">
   <test-plaid
    [form]="plaidLinkToken"
     [plaidLinkToken]="plaidLinkToken$ | async"
     (plaidLinkSuccess)="plaidExchangeToken($event)"
   ></test-plaid>
 </ng-container>
```

declarations.d.ts

```
declare const Plaid: PlaidLink;

interface PlaidLink {
  create: (config: LinkConfig) => LinkHandler;
  readonly version: string;
}

interface LinkHandler {
  open: (institution?: string) => void;
  exit: (config?: LinkHandlerExitConfig) => void;
}

interface LinkConfig {
  clientName: string;
  env: string;
  forceIframe?: boolean;
  isWebView?: boolean;
  product: string[];
  selectAccount?: boolean;
  token?: string;
  webhook?: string;
  onLoad: () => void;
  onExit: (error: LinkOnExitError, metadata: LinkOnExitMetadata) => void;
  onSuccess: (public_token: string, metadata: LinkOnSuccessMetadata) => void;
}
```

Comment: your event emitting and handling code looks correct to me. doubt that's the reason but have you tried to call eventEmitter as instance field rather than static ? You will need to bind context Plaid.create(...).bind(this) so callback has access to component scope

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I think it could well be because the EventEmitter property is a static property.

Comment: PlaidComponent.plaidLinkSuccess.emit({
Since I am doing this I need to have the emitter has to be a static field for it to be accessible.
Also I tried doing the .bind and got that it does not exist on type LinkHandler.